# Print to standard output all folders matching a certain pattern

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to find all the folders which are named as 3 numbers (###) *and* has a subdirectory which are named as 2 numbers (##).

**What I tried:**

My approach to this problem was to use the `find` command. Where I would look for a pattern like this:

```
### (folder name)
  -> ## (subdirectory name)
```

Since the depth must be two I used `-maxdepth 2`

To find the naming pattern I used `'[0-9][0-9][0-9]'` to get the main folder name, and used `'[0-9][0-9]'` to get the name of the subdirectory.

Putting this together I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' -type d); do
    echo $f
done
```

The part that's left out is the part I can't seem to figure out. How do you add the naming pattern of the subdirectory to the find command so that it finds all folders matching the pattern ### as the main folder name *and* ## as the subdirectory name.

If anyone could give me a hint to this problem that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly with globs, since they can span directories:

```
echo [0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/
```